# How to concatenate the list elements

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Here I'm having the list of list, i want to concatenate only the first two elements if the second element of list has name. else do nothing.

The below is the code which i tried:

```
lst_1 = [['ANTWERP' 'BRIDGE', '05', 'N'], 
         ['NORTHERN' 'VIGOUR', '05', 'N'],
         ['BRIDGE', '98', 'N']]
for i in lst_1:
    for j in i:               
        j[0:2] = ['_'.join(j[0:2])]
```

expected output:

```
[['ANTWERP_BRIDGE', '05', 'N'], 
 ['NORTHERN_VIGOUR', '05', 'N'],
 ['BRIDGE', '98', 'N']]
```

can i find any way to do this?

Comment: `lst_1` currently raises a SyntaxError. Please [edit]

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the inner list, just test (`if`, not `for`)

Comment: What do you mean by "if the second element of list has name"?

Comment: @Sayse That appears to be the answer to my question. That element only has one name, not two names that need to be joined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to decide what it means for the second element to be a name. I suggest two possibilities. One is to check the length of the sub-list:

```
if len(i) == 4:
```

Another is to check for integers:

```
if len(i) > 2 and not i[1].isdigit():
```

In either case, you can merge pretty much as you did before, but with an `if` instead of the inner `for` loop:

```
for i in lst_1:
    if <condition>:
        i[:2] = ['_'.join(i[:2])]
```

This modifies `lst_1` in-place. If you want to replace it with a new object, use [@Sayse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68292510/2988730).

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't over think it, simply just concatenate the elements then add on the rest

```
 [[f"{i[0]}_{i[1]}" if len(i) == 4 else i[0], *i[-2:]] for i in lst_1]
```

Comment: You missed the point about only elements with two names (not all of them) needing to be joined.

Comment: @Barmar. Not if you want to skip `i[1]`

Comment: Very neat solution